# How to breakdown an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and i need to classify each object by name and then get the addition of some properties.

To be more specific, I have a cart with some orders and i need to breakdown by product name so i can calculate how many items of that product were bought.

```
const orders = [
{
    name: 'Isaac',
    products: [
      {
        name: 'Apple',
        unit: 'x6 und',
        qty: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Lemon',
        unit: '500gr',
        qty: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Coconut',
        unit: 'x3 und',
        qty: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Orange',
        unit: 'kg',
        qty: 1
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Andrea',
    products: [
      {
        name: 'Apple',
        unit: 'x6 und',
        qty: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Lemon',
        unit: '500gr',
        qty: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Coconut',
        unit: 'x3 und',
        qty: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Garlic',
        unit: '250 gr',
        qty: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'George',
    products: [
      {
        name: 'Apple',
        unit: 'x6 und',
        qty: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Lemon',
        unit: '500gr',
        qty: 4
      },
      {
        name: 'Coconut',
        unit: 'x3 und',
        qty: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Garlic',
        unit: '250 gr',
        qty: 1
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

That is the dummy data,

I mapped the orders array and then mapped the products array, then i used .flat() method to get another array of objects but simplified.

Now I am stuck.

```
const resume = orders.map(order => {
return order.products.map(prods => {
    return prods
  })
})

console.log(resume.flat());
```

This is the result:

```
    [
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Orange', unit: 'kg', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x12 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Garlic', unit: '250 gr', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 4 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Garlic', unit: '250 gr', qty: 1 }
]
```

At this point, i need to know how many apples, Coconut, Garlic were sold.

Example: name: 'Apple', unit: 'X6 und', qty: 6
name: 'Apple', unit: 'X12 und', qty: 1
name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 9
an so on...

Any clue? I am completely lost :(

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce reduce the elements so the names do not repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not as elegant as `reduce`, but kind of fun, is the following:
Starting with your original `orders` (no need for the intermediate step, unless you want it), initiate an empty array, like `ordersArray = []`, and run the following:

```
orders.forEach((order) => {
  order.products.forEach((product) => {
    const index = ordersArray.findIndex((prod) => prod.name === product.name);
      index === -1 ? ordersArray.push(product) : ordersArray[index].qty += product.qty  
  });
});
```

Your result is:

```
ordersArray = [
   { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 6 },
   { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 9 },
   { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 6 },
   { name: 'Orange', unit: 'kg', qty: 1 },
   { name: 'Garlic', unit: '250 gr', qty: 3 },
 ]
```

This *looks* right (I'm not sure where the `{ name: 'Apple', unit: 'x12 und', qty: 2 }` object came from for your intermediate step :) ).
Lately, I've been storing this kind of information in an object (see [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-why-you-should-use-an-object-not-an-array-for-lists-bee4a1fbc8bd)). It would be very similar, with only slight differences: Start with the same `orders` (obviously), and then define an empty object `ordersObject = {}`.

```
orders.forEach((order) => {
  order.products.forEach((product) => {
    ordersObject[product.name] = { unit: product.unit, qty: (ordersObject[product.name]?.qty || 0) + product.qty }
  });
});
```

The result is similar, but easier to update, retrieve data, etc.

```
ordersObject = {
  Apple: { unit: 'x6 und', qty: 6 },
  Lemon: { unit: '500gr', qty: 9 },
  Coconut: { unit: 'x3 und', qty: 6 },
  Orange: { unit: 'kg', qty: 1 },
  Garlic: { unit: '250 gr', qty: 3 }
}
```

Comment: I just needed to make a simple update. Apple X12 und is a different presentations, but was my mistake, i forgot to update the dummy data. The update i made was: 
orders.forEach((order) => {
  order.products.forEach((product) => {
    const index = ordersArray.findIndex((prod) => prod.name === product.name && prod.unit === product.unit);
      index === -1 ? ordersArray.push(product) : ordersArray[index].qty += product.qty  
  });
});
Thank you so much for your help. I will try with the object version. Take care my friend.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const orders = [
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Orange', unit: 'kg', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x12 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Garlic', unit: '250 gr', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 4 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Garlic', unit: '250 gr', qty: 1 }
]

const getQuantityItem = (orders, item) => orders.reduce((acc,val)=>{
acc+=val.name===item? val.qty: 0;
return acc;
},0);

console.log(getQuantityItem(orders, 'Apple'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map or object to group items, known as a "groupBy" operation.

You can combine the `name` and `unit` values together to use as keys to account for same name but different units in order to get unique object for each name & unit measure. Assigning a productId might also be helpful and use that for grouping.

You could also modify to nest different measures/qtys under one name if you prefer

```js
const group = data.reduce((m, {name, unit, qty})=>{
   const key = `${name}|${unit}`;
   if(!m.has(key)){
      m.set(key, {name, unit, qty:0})
   }
   m.get(key).qty += qty;
   return m;
}, new Map);

const res = [...group.values()].sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {   max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```

```html
<script>

   const data= [
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Orange', unit: 'kg', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x12 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Garlic', unit: '250 gr', qty: 2 },
  { name: 'Apple', unit: 'x6 und', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Lemon', unit: '500gr', qty: 4 },
  { name: 'Coconut', unit: 'x3 und', qty: 3 },
  { name: 'Garlic', unit: '250 gr', qty: 1 }
]
</script>
```